# Basic java code error due to styling

Tags: java, android

I was all fine app running on phone etc until I added a style folder from tutorial, now I get errors when running the program on the phone but the preview looks right. Wondering can anyone give it to me in simpleton terms as I'm very new to coding Thanks x
Style xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Primary theme color of the app (sets background color of app bar) -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF9800</item>
        <!-- Background color of buttons in the app -->
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#FF9800</item>
        </style>
        </resources>
```

JAVA -

```
    package com.example.android.courtcounter;



 import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int ScoreTeamA = 0;
    int ScoreTeamB = 0;

    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team A.
     */
    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }
    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team B.
     */
    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        displayForTeamA(ScoreTeamA);
    }

    /**
     * Adds 3 to team A.
     */
    public void scoreThree(View view){
        ScoreTeamA = ScoreTeamA + 3;
        displayForTeamA(ScoreTeamA);
    }
    /**
     * Adds 2 to team A.
     */
    public void scoreTwo(View view){
        ScoreTeamA = ScoreTeamA + 2;
        displayForTeamA(ScoreTeamA);
    }
    /**
     * Adds 1 to team A.
     */
    public void scoreFreeThrow(View view){
        ScoreTeamA = ScoreTeamA + 1;
        displayForTeamA(ScoreTeamA);
    }
    /**
     * Adds 3 to team B.
     */
    public void scoreThreeB(View view){
        ScoreTeamB = ScoreTeamB + 3;
        displayForTeamB(ScoreTeamB);
    }
    /**
     * Adds 2 to team B.
     */
    public void scoreTwoB(View view){
        ScoreTeamB = ScoreTeamB + 2;
        displayForTeamB(ScoreTeamB);
    }
    /**
     * Adds 1 to team B.
     */
    public void scoreFreeThrowB(View view){
        ScoreTeamB = ScoreTeamB + 1;
        displayForTeamB(ScoreTeamB);
    }

    public void reset(View view){
        ScoreTeamA = 0;
        ScoreTeamB = 0;
        displayForTeamB(ScoreTeamB);
        displayForTeamA(ScoreTeamA);
    }
}
```

XML - main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Team A" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:textSize="56sp"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:onClick="scoreThree"
                android:text="3 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:onClick="scoreTwo"
                android:text="2 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:onClick="scoreFreeThrow"
                android:text="FREE THROW" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <view
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Team B" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_b_score"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:textSize="56sp"
                android:text="0" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:onClick="scoreThreeB"
                android:text="3 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:onClick="scoreTwoB"
                android:text="2 Points" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:onClick="scoreFreeThrowB"
                android:text="FREE THROW" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:onClick="reset"
            android:text="RESET SCORES" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and my debug error says 
"

```
12/10 16:07:57: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.android.courtcounter/com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.android.courtcounter | com.example.android.courtcounter.test
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.android.courtcounter | com.example.android.courtcounter.test
Connecting to com.example.android.courtcounter
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.android.courtcounter is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1485)
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,-div,-atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a53 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.android.courtcounter-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.android.courtcounter-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/BoostFramework: mAcquireFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquire(int,int[])
V/BoostFramework: mReleaseFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockRelease()
V/BoostFramework: mAcquireTouchFunc method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfLockAcquireTouch(android.view.MotionEvent,android.util.DisplayMetrics,int,int[])
V/BoostFramework: mIOPStart method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStart(int,java.lang.String)
V/BoostFramework: mIOPStop method = public int com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfIOPrefetchStop()
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@cf6d61
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@5ab5086
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.android.courtcounter, PID: 24781
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.courtcounter/com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                      at com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6294)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:738)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                      at com.example.android.courtcounter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30) 
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6294) 
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24781 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'"
```

I'm not really sure where to start on this because it ws working fine until I added the style text tot he style folder and it's now just crashing on the devise with the error message "Unfortunately, courtcounter has stopped."

I'm at a loss as to how to resolve this I've tried searching for resolutions but the error code wasn't there before styling :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a typo in your XML file. Specifically:

```
    <!-- Uhoh. "view" should be "View." -->
    <view
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

If you fix that typo you should be good to go.

Comment: update Yay aww thank you there was no hint that was wrong cheers mate x could kiss ya x